# Find the next number in this series

Tags: number-sequence

The sequence is:

> 4,7,7,0,1,1,4,8,3,2,3,9,4,1,5,3,0,6,4,5,0,5,1,0,9,1,2,7,7,1,4,9,5,5,6,9,5,1,?

It's very simple indeed you won't need to do any calculation, but you may need to do a little one, good luck. Yes you may really need to read this hint.

**Hint1:**

> Three things make up it, one of them is the first of Good Boy. A cat tamed the boy. The third one is an acronym relating to computer networks.

**Hint2:**

> It is neither due to Euler, nor by Apery.

**Hint3:**[New]

> Some constant perhaps?

**Edit:** Hint edited.

**Edit2:** Ok I may add other hints if you comment something (maybe the problem you're facing or which type of hint should be there).

Comment: Hint 2 tells me it's something to do with the Riemann zeta function

Comment: Is Hint 1 anything to do with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Boy!)?

Comment: @randal'thor nope, don't go on the meanings really of it

Comment: Based on the hints: Is it really a "number-sequence" puzzle or rather a riddle/cryptogram? i.e. what is the next letter in "This is a wonderful puzzl" is *not* a letter-sequence puzzle!

Comment: @BmyGuest Well I'm not well going into English. I can only say that they are interrelated to each other and there's no riddle cryptogram. They form together something I may call it a series, if you agree.

Comment: @ADG Hmm, so it can be a combination of constants leading to a number which gives the sequence... ? Not sure if this matches "finding the hidden pattern", but maybe it is...  But it does become a bit arbitrary then, and the "puzzle" part is rather the deciphering of your (riddle) hints than the actual number-sequence... Not saying it's a bad puzzle - but maybe it needs different tags? (Or not! If my assumptions are wrong.)

Comment: @BmyGuest ignore hint 1, now hint 2 and hint 3 are more than sufficient to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is a mean puzzle that I just happened to solve because I got lucky. It is unsolvable without the hints.

The answer is:

> 9

Reasoning:

> The number sequence is Catalan's constant backwards, starting arbitrarily 39 digits from the decimal point.

Hint 1:

> It is referred to by a capital G in mathematics, a cat tamed the boy (refers to cata, not sure why), and LAN stands for local area network.

Hint 2 and 3:

> It is a constant that isn't Euler's or Apery's.

How I figured it out:

> The hints and random googling made me sure the answer had something to do with Catalan many days ago, but no matter what transformations I did I couldn't find the connection. After revisiting, by chance I happened to notice the constant on the Wikipedia page had the same number of digits (39) as the puzzle and from there I saw the connection. A bit mean but I guess solvable.